# Python, Pandas: Combining Dataframe with Dictionary (by Conditions)

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

Good day all of you,

I have a dataframe similiar to this:

```
id    |    name    |    personnelNumber
1     |    abcd    |    00013
2     |    efgh    |    00142
19    |    abcd    |    00013
84    |    abcd    |    00013
103   |    efgh    |    00142
117   |    mnop    |    00087
```

I also have dictionary with random values and the 'personnelNumber' like in my dataframe:

```
{'00013': 41, '00087': 725, '00142': 19}
```

My question: Is there a way to add the values into a new column, based on a matching 'personnelNumber'? I'd like to receice something like this:

```
id    |    name    |    personnelNumber    |    value
1     |    abcd    |    00013              |    41
2     |    efgh    |    00142              |    19
19    |    abcd    |    00013              |    41
84    |    abcd    |    00013              |    41
103   |    efgh    |    00142              |    19
117   |    mnop    |    00087              |    725
```

Thanks for all advices and help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `personnelNumber` is of type `string` (because of the leading zeros), you can use [`pd.Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html)

```py
d = {'00013': 41, '00087': 725, '00142': 19}

df['value'] = df.personnelNumber.map(d)
df
```

Out:

```
    id  name personnelNumber  value
0    1  abcd           00013     41
1    2  efgh           00142     19
2   19  abcd           00013     41
3   84  abcd           00013     41
4  103  efgh           00142     19
5  117  mnop           00087    725
```